# Windows Form publish to a different application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

I have a Windows Form application. Version 1 of my app has been released for a while and client is using it. Version 1 of the app is connected to the production database.

I have been developing on version 2 of the app and I plan to released a beta version for the client. Version 2 of the app will be connected to the test database, so the client can play around with it, make sure everything is working as they like. But the client still need to use version 1 of the app to get their work done.

My question is what I need to change to the publish setting so I can publish v2 as a separate application, and the client can launch both v1 and v2 of the app.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "publish setting"? ClickOnce?

Comment: What I mean is in Visual Studio, double-click on the Properties folder. Then go to the Publish tab. I think I need to change th Publishing Folder and the Publish Version. I am not sure which other settings I need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to change the Publishing Folder and the GUID. That's it!